# Face not detect when change orientation?

Tags: android

I have problem with face detection. When I change the orientation of my device from landscape to portrait, face detection fails.

I am unable to find a solution. This is what I tried:

```
if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) { 
    mCamera = Camera.open(camIdx);
    Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
    params.set("orientation", "portrait");
    //params.set("rotation", 90);           
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    //params.setRotation(90);
    //params.setPictureSize(640, 480);
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
    mCamera.startPreview();
}
```

Whenever I change the orientation of my device, I did'nt got face detect .
please anybody help me, i did try all thinks but not able detect face.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if your are doing live detection or still images, but this might help if you are trying to detect faces for still portraits. Take the image you have from the camera in portrait mode and put them in to a imageview that you define in java. The imageview should be set to be wider than it is tall. Now that you have the imageView with the correct dimensions and a portrait loaded on it, save the view as a bitmap using this:

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = view.getDrawingCache();
```

Use face detection on the resulting bitmap. This should work because faceDetection is technically looking at a landscape image with a black background. 
Also face detection doesn't work for portraits mode, period.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void setCameraDisplayOrientation(Activity activity,
         int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
             new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
             .getRotation();
     int degrees = 0;
     switch (rotation) {
         case Surface.ROTATION_0: degrees = 0; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_90: degrees = 90; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_180: degrees = 180; break;
         case Surface.ROTATION_270: degrees = 270; break;
     }

     int result;
     if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
         result = (360 - result) % 360;  // compensate the mirror
     } else {  // back-facing
         result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
     }
     camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
 }
```

Comment: Might be more helpful if you can explain what your code does and how it answers the question.